# GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener. How do I detect an ACTION_UP event?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-event, android-gesture

Using this

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
```

Only detects for single tap event i.e. quick tap and release. 
If i hold down and then release, `onSingleTapUp` is not called.

I am looking for an motion event which is `ACTION_UP` after holding down.

I looked at `onShowPress` which is called when the user performs a down action but then I was not sure how to detect a `ACTION_UP` while in `onShowPress`.

Note this is for a `recycler view` to click items. At the moment, I can single tap an item which works but if I hold it down and then release, it is not invoked.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @Eselfar Hi, I did not solve this particular issue but used a different solution altogether to solve my problem which was to set a OnClickListener on the itemView itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass your view and override `onTouchEvent`. That will let you observe the different actions before the gesture detector handles them.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    int action = e.getActionMasked();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // do something here
    }

    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following in your `onSingleTapUp` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    // Do what you want
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I tried the code but it did not work. I can still only single tap an item. I will post some code soon